# Align axes across subfigures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, subfloats

How can I align the y axes of subsequent subfigures horizontally? Like in this test case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \pgfplotsset{
        my plot/.style = {
            width = \linewidth,
            height = 4cm,
            axis lines = left
        }
    }
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[my plot]
                \addplot {rand};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{first}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[my plot]
                \addplot {rand*100};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{second}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[my plot]
                \addplot {rand*5000};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{third}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{test figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Axes should be on top of each other, on the red line, but they are shifted horizontally because of different y tick label widths.

[image]

I have a feeling that a combination of `extra y ticks` and `hphantom` to accomodate the widest tick label could work, but I haven't been able to figure anything out.

Another possibility I haven't been able to make work is to wrap each label in `rlap` to collapse their width and right-align them.

The `ymin` and `ymax` are known for each of the subfigures, so I can potentially hardcode them if that turns out to be a solution.

Comment: what looks to be the difference here is the width of the labels on the y axis.  if you could force those all to the same width, the axes should align.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how I could do that?

Comment: unfortunately, i'm barely a novice tikz user, so i'd have to dig through the manual to figure it out.  (i was hoping the suggestion might spur some more experienced user to make an effort.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. Adding the option `trim axis left` to the `tikzpicture` chops off everything left of the axis. Combined with `\centering` before the `subfigure` this aligns the plots nicely.

```
\begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
        \begin{axis}[my plot]
            ...
```

[image]