# Align tikz subfigures correctly while respecting margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, subfloats, subfig

I have a document where I include different subfigures using tikz. The problem is, that the numbers on the y-axis of the subfigures can have different length, which results in subfigures that are not correctly aligned (horizontally).

I already found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246218/156345) answer to a very similar question, which proposes to use the `trim axis left` option. This solves the alignment problem, but the labels then don't respect the page margin anymore.

Here is my example code which reproduces the problem (`trim axis left` commented out):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\columnwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[%
axis line style = thick,
width=4in,height=1in,at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1,
axis x line*=bottom,axis y line*=left
]
\addplot [color=red,dashed,line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0.1\\
9   0.9\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\columnwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[%
axis line style = thick,
width=4in,height=1in,at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=9000,
axis x line*=bottom,axis y line*=left
]
\addplot [color=red,dashed,line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   1000\\
9   9000\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Here is an image that shows the problem:

[image]

I want both images to be aligned horizontally while still respecting the page margin.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Are you in two-column mode?

Comment: @Bernard No I just copied the screenshots next to each other to show the problem.

Comment: So actually, you want the images to be *vertically* aligned (while respecting tha margins)?

Comment: @Bernard I want them like in the second image (so that the y-axes of the plots are at the same position horizontally). But the  plot should be more on the right so that the y labels respect the page margin.

Comment: A simple dirty trick:  add  `\quad` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` in  the upper subfigure.

Comment: @Bernard Ok, that works in this specific case but I would prefer a more general solution because I have more such figures. If I increase ymax in the lower subfigure to 90000 for example, the trick doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You have to adapt to `\hskip relevant length`. I did try a more general solution nesting each subfigure in an `\eqparbox` with the same tag for both, and adding `\raggedleft` to have both tikzpicture right aligned, but there's a compatibility problem – I have an error message.

Comment: you need to make images narrower, for example equal to `0.8\linewidth` and than use `[trim axis left,trim axis right] ` at each `tikzpicture`

Comment: @Zarko That seems to work.

Comment: Are you going to add a `\caption{..}` inside each `subfigure`? If not, there's not really much point in using subfigures in the first place, place both axes in the same `tikzpicture` using a `groupplot`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes I use captions for each subfigure I just wanted a small example code so I didn't put them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way how to solve your problem -- as mentioned in my comment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,
             axis lines=left,
             axis line style = thick,
             scale only axis
            }
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.8\columnwidth} % narower subfigure
                                     % determine diagram width
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right] 
\begin{axis}[height=1in,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
\addplot [color=red,dashed,line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0.1\\
9   0.9\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.8\columnwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right] 
\begin{axis}[height=1in,%
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=9000,
]
\addplot [color=red,dashed,line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   1000\\
9   9000\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]